# How to say "timestamp" in Russian?

Tags: перевод, терминология

Timestamps are widely used in programming. I am trying to write a description of my code in Russian, and I'm stuck at *timestamps*. [Wikipedia suggests](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) the term *временная метка*, but quite reluctantly, as if there was no "official" term. I wonder if there is any.

Comment: На мультитране ["временной маркёр"](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=3&&s=timestamp&l1=1&l2=2) и еще несколько вариаций на тему ["временнЫх (от)меток"](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=timestamp&l1=1).

Comment: My friend who is a top manager in a programming company says they say "метка времени."

Comment: @Artemix И совершенно напрасно дает. Если верить [Гуглю](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%22), то этот «временной маркер» может значить что угодно: от точки привязки относительной шкалы к абсолютной в исторической лигвистике или геологии до указателя в интерфейсе редактора линейного монтажа, но только не _timestamp_ в криптографическом смысле.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Википедия здесь, как ни неожиданно, абсолютна права, называя русскую статью «Timestamp» — так на самом деле и говорят по-русски: «таймстамп». ИТ — это, наверное, отрасль с самой высокой концентрацией прямых английских заимствований.

А гостовский термин — *отметка времени*, см. хотя бы знаменитый [ГОСТ 28147–89 на странице 16](http://protect.gost.ru/v.aspx?control=8&baseC=-1&page=0&month=-1&year=-1&search=&RegNum=1&DocOnPageCount=15&id=131282&pageK=482D6C28-F2B4-410E-AF8D-3ADE90F6AE78).

По гугль-тесту он, кстати, тоже лидирует среди русских, солидно опережая *метку времени*, *временную метку*, но не *таймстамп*:

- таймстамп — [867 000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%22)
- отметка времени — [103 000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22)
- временная метка — [11 000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%22)
- метка времени — [20 000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22)

Comment: замечательный ответ, я бы только добавил, что таймстэмп тоже говорят.

Comment: Никак не могу принять википедийный вариант (английское написание). Всё-таки, русский язык отличается транслитерацией заимствованных слов. Спасибо за ГОСТ, этому я обычно доверяю с удовольствием. А поиск в Гугле, кстати, в этом случае вряд ли можно считать показателем: за неимением ясного русского термина, народ просто использует прямую транслитерацию: все профессионалы безусловно поймут. Сойдёмся на _таймстампе_ и _отметке времени_.

Comment: @texnic Только в мёртвом языке правила не меняются. То что вы говорите по-английски характеризуется как "No true scottsman fallacy", не знаю как это даже выразить по-русски.

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще перевести как "момент времени". Заимствование 'таймстамп' выглядит очень коряво и скорее всего вы будете не поняты за пределами it-сообщества или людей, знающих английский.

Comment: Ну, в данном конкретном случае, вряд ли можно ожидать что "описание кода по-русски" будут читать люди далекие от it-сообщества.

Comment: @Artemix, аргумент разумный, но тогда можно просто написать по-английски, и все (программисты) поймут. Хочется именно найти эквивалент, если он есть. _Момент времени_ мне тоже нравится, хотя исходный вопрос был про общепринятый, официальный перевод.

Comment: Речь про перевод, а не про то, чтобы было просто понятно. Документацию могут читать люди не всегда, связанные с программированием. ПЕРЕВОДИТЬ как таймтемп точно нельзя. А то это тоже самое, что "ЛЕТ МИ СПИК ФРОМ МАЙ ХАРТ ИН ИНГЛИШ" - все понятно, но это не перевод ;)

Answer (score -2):

Ещё можно сказать:

- Засечка, как Робинзон Крузо ставил засечки, сколько лет он прожил на острове.
- точка отсчёта
- Или просто `дата`. timestamp - это ни что иное, как дата, дата времени.

Comment: _Точка отсчёта_ не подходит по смыслу: точка отсчёта обычно одна, временных меток много. _Дата_ тоже явно не то, т.к. что со временем? _Дата времени_ — это как яблоко апельсина.